# How is the dotted decimal IP address "1.2.3.4.5" interpreted and resolved?

Tags: dns, mac

The Apache Mina Ftpserver project has a unit test that checks that the IP address `1.2.3.4.5` fails to be resolved by the OS's name resolution.  Specifically, the expected result of:

```
InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4.5")
```

is "unknown host".

When I run this on Mac OS X 10.9.2, the (what appears to be a) dotted decimal IP address `1.2.3.4.5` does in fact resolve to an IP address.  Based on who owns the resolved IP, it appears to belong to my ISP (and I doubt this is coincidental).

What is happening here?  How is `1.2.3.4.5` being interpreted and resolved in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your ISP serving an error page instead of sending NXDOMAIN errors?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking#Manipulation_by_ISPs

Try visiting the page in your browser. If you're seeing an error page that is not generated by your browser, consider configuring your system to use a third-party DNS server, such as [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Comment: The browser request responded with 'Bad Request (Invalid Hostname), and switching to Google DNS has fixed it (ping now reports unknown host).

Answer (score -1):

You can't have an IP address like this one (1.2.3.4.5).
IP address has to be 4 octets only (1.2.3.4)
This is not an IP address, and it will never resolve!